# In InnoDB, does a Transaction imply any implicit locking of a table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, transaction

The Isolation level is REPEATABLE_READ.

The logic is as under:

```
Transaction begins
Read data from Table A
If (Table A has Any Data) End Transaction and exit
If Table A has No Data, Proceed further
Delete a record in Table B
Transaction ends
```

Now, my question is about the following scenario:

- The current execution reaches at point #4.
- I someone inserts data (Note, the current execution is at point # 4) in the Table A that would have returned some result in #2.
- Now, The current execution will execute #5. It will delete a record that should not be deleted.

Is there any implicit locking in transaction or do I need to lock Table A Explicitly so no one can insert any data in Table A before I commit changes?

Comment: Note, if someone inserts data .... Here, I am talking about another transaction (let's say some 3rd party) inserting data in the Table A

Answer (score 3):

In repeatable reads, there is always row-level locking imposed via the [**gen_clust_index (aka the Clustered Index)**](https://serverfault.com/a/239554/69271). This is the beauty of Transactions. What is even more interesting is that InnoDB has four [*transaction isolation levels*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tx_isolation), not just one:

There are four values for tx_isolation you can set:

- [READ-UNCOMMITTED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted)
- [READ-COMMITTED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-committed)
- [REPEATABLE-READ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) (default)
- [SERIALIZABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_serializable)

In your particular case, inserting data into TableA actually does not get written to disk. The necessary changes are recorded in three(3) distinct places:

1. log buffer in memory
2. in ibdata1

   - undo tablespace
   - rollback segments
   - double write buffer
3. redo log info in either ib_logfile0 or ib_logfile1

The same applies with the delete in step 5.

Executing a rollback will undo the delete and then undo the inserts.

You must remember something very important: If you want to rollback multiple SQL commands, you must begin like this:

```
SET autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION;

Transaction begins
Read data from Table A
If (Table A has Any Data) End Transaction (via ROLLBACK) and exit
If Table A has No Data, Proceed further
Delete a record in Table B
Transaction ends

COMMIT;
```

Give it a Try !!!

When everyone is using repeatable reads

- your INSERTs are only seen by you
- someone else's DELETEs are only seen by the other person

CAVEAT : Table level locking is never implicit for InnoDB. If you want to lock a table, you must issue, `LOCK TABLE` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question was about another transaction inserting data and committing before the `current transaction` commits it.

Comment: can a 3rd party insert something in the Table A during my transaction?

Comment: In a repeatable read situation, yes data can be inserted, especially if autocommit=1 (which is the default).

Comment: Is there any other option available other than locking a table? And second thing is, I believe innodb has row level locking, so 3rd party won't be able to update the records that are read by my transaction. right?

Comment: This depends on the app. If the app does not set set up a transaction with `START TRANSACTION...COMMIT/ROLLBACK;`, then the app with be just another client connection doing exactly what you are doing: writing to a common table. If the app does not use `set autocomnit = 0;` then it goes back to what I stated before: In a repeatable read situation, yes data can be inserted, especially if autocommit=1 (which is the default).

Comment: "read data" should probably be SELECT ... FOR UPDATE.

Comment: Autocommit=0 is unnecessary in the context if an explicit transaction. It only is necessary when executing individual statements outside the context of a transaction to implicitly create one.

Comment: To be more clear, START TRANSACTION implicitly sets autocommit=0, so it is unnecessary to execute it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test about locking. I started two connections which called A and B to execute commands. The operation flow list as below.

1. A: set autocommit=0;
2. A: update sometable set status = 0 where columns_a in(234,333) and is_del=0;
3. B: set autocommit=0;
4. B: update sometable set status = 0 where columns_a in(222,444) and is_del=0;
5. A: commit;
6. B: commit;

scenarios A:
If columns_a is set as primary key of the sometable, step 4 executed and finished immediately.

scenarios B:
If columns_a isn't the primary key, but we had add an index on column_a of sometable, step 4 executed and finished immediately.

scenarios C:
If columns_a is set as primary key of the sometable, step 4 executed and finished in no time.

scenarios D:
If columns_a isn't the primary key, step 4 would be waiting for the lock until step 5 executed.

I wonder if the 'lock' is table level lock which be attempt to acquire by step 4 in scenarios D .